# decode two values using oracle decode

Tags: oracle

```
select status_a,status_b from test
```

how to decode `status_a`,`status_b` below values using  oracle decode function aand if one of the values of status_a or status_b is null.

```
if  status_a='Y' and status_b='Y' then 'Y'

if  status_a='Y' and status_b='N' then 'N'

if  status_a='N' and status_b='Y' then 'N'

if  status_a='N' and status_b='N' then 'N'
```

Regards,

Chaituhara

Comment: Are you 'or' statements meant to be 'and'? I don't think this makes sense as it is e.g. if status_a = 'Y' and status_b = 'N' should the result be 'Y' or 'N'? Both of your first two lines would be true for this scenario.

Answer (score 8):

Why do you want to use `DECODE`?  `CASE` would seem like a much better fit

```
CASE WHEN status_a = 'Y' and status_b = 'Y' THEN 'Y'
     WHEN status_a = 'Y' and status_b = 'N' THEN 'N'
     WHEN status_a = 'N' and status_b = 'Y' THEN 'N'
     WHEN status_a = 'N' and status_b = 'N' THEN 'N'
  END
```

Of course, the logic you posted does not appear to make sense.  The only way that `status_a = 'Y' or status_b = 'Y'` would evaluate to FALSE while `status_a = 'Y' or status_b = 'N'` evaluated to TRUE would be if `status_a = 'N'` and `status_b = 'N'`.  But that means that the third and fourth branch would never be reached.  If you meant `and` rather than `or`, the logic would make sense.  But in that case, you could simplify it to

```
CASE WHEN status_a = 'Y' and status_b = 'Y' THEN 'Y'
     ELSE 'N'
  END
```

Comment: I changed the `or` to `and` to match the OP.

Comment: @user2750658 . . . Why would you want to use `decode()` instead of the more powerful and standard `case` statement?

Comment: @user2750658 - Why does the nullability matter?  Anything you can do with `DECODE` you can do with `CASE`.  And `CASE` is generally easier and more standard.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean AND rather than OR then this can be done using a decode:

```
decode(status_a,'Y',
       decode(status_b,'Y','Y','N'),
       'N')
```

or this could be simplified to:

```
decode(status_a||status_b,'YY','Y','N')
```

Comment: thanks chris,how it works if one of the values either status_a or status_b value is null

Comment: @user2750658 I would expect this to evaluate to 'N'. Unfortunately, I am not at a computer where I can test this right now. If this was not the case then it could be handled with a nvl, but this would surprise me. Would you want this to evaluate to 'N'?

Comment: and one more thing either of the value is N.value should be Y. ex:status_a =Y and status_b=N then return value should be Y

Answer (score 1):

Based on your last comment I guessing ,you are saying that either of value is Y then the result should be Y and also in case either one is null then also it should be Y.

I hope below decode works fine to meet your requirement.

```
decode(status_a||Status_b,'YY','Y','YN','Y','NY','Y','NN','N','Y')
```

Correction:

```
select decode(status_a||status_b,'YY','Y','YN','N','NY','N','NN','N','') as result from test;
--syntax of DECODE: decode(expression, 'match1', 'result1', 'match2', 'result2', 'match3', 'result3', 'matchN', 'resultN', 'defaultIfNoMatch')
```

Comment: can I know the error ,is it in logic or syntactical?  This helps me retry.

Comment: I think your solution is the best after looking at others. I've just corrected your answer to make it more accurate to the posted question.